# Hands on table in salesforce

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have created one picklist.the values are copy/paste and manuelenter.once user select the copy/paste value,the value copy from excel sheet to vf page and once user select the manuelenter,the value entered by user manually.how to achieve this one?